# Turning off Autocommit in Visual Fox Pro?

Tags: transactions, visual-foxpro, autocommit

I begin my transactions in VFP9 with `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and end them with `ROLLBACK` but the changes persist anyway.

I'm using a free table directory and I think maybe the issue might have something to do with buffering but I don't know how to apply this to a free table database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into CursorSetProp()

The default setting is NO BUFFERING at either the table or record level.  After the table is open, issue the cursorsetprop  (even if its an actual table) and the transaction processing will be respected...

```
USE YourTable
CURSORSETPROP("Buffering", 4, "YourTable" )

1 = no buffering
2 = pessimistic row buffering
3 = optimistic row buffering
4 = Pessimistic Table Buffering
5 = Optimistic Table Buffering
```